# What is the term for whether a question can be answered or not?

Tags: single-word-requests

Or I guess the "answerability" of a question.

Comment: What is wrong with https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/answerable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be helpful to borrow a word from computer science here, where this property is called [*decidability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem). Informally, a question is *decidable* if it possible to ask it and follow some steps to get an answer. Otherwise, it is *undecidable*.

An example of an undecidable problem is the famous Halting Problem, which can be informally phrased as "will this program eventually stop running, or will it run forever?" It turns out there's no way to construct a set of steps — an *algorithm* — to answer this question.

If a problem is technically not undecidable, but just very hard to answer, you can use *intractable* instead.

Comment: Odd that I'd have to turn to computer science/logic terminology to find my answer and that it's not in common terminology as I expected Philosophy would have a term for it.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in a comment, the adjective is [**answerable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/answerable):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2** : capable of being answered or refuted
>
> // There has been a controversy on the question of whether the species was genetically closer to the horse or to the zebra. This question may possibly be *answerable* now that DNA from the three species is available for comparison.
> — Harold M. Schmeck Jr. an answerable assertion

---

Also, despite the fact that you put *answerability* in quotation marks, suggesting that you thought you were making it up, *answerability* ***is*** a real word.

However, the meaning of its noun form corresponds to a different sense of the adjective *answerable*.

I will provide the definition from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/answerability), since Merriam-Webster, although listing it as a noun, doesn't actually define it:

> Responsibility for explaining or justifying one's actions.
> ‘the answerability of governments to the citizenry’

In theory, although not shown that way, I don't see why it couldn't also be used in the sense you want for it:

> I doubt the *answerability* of that question. Are you sure it's *answerable*?

Comment: The reason I put answerability in quotations is that I like you found no definition that fit the word I'm looking for. I suppose answerable is sufficient but I'm looking for a word that can fit in the sentence:

I first have to determine the ____ of the question.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the answerer, right? The only term I can find is in some research: question difficulty estimation. https://aclweb.org/anthology/D/D13/D13-1009.pdf

Comment: I'm not referring to difficulty of the question which would be dependant on the answerer but rather the possibility of the question being answered or not. For example, the question "Is the fish in the water?" is impossible to answer.